# throw Exception with InnerException c#

Tags: c#, exception

I'm working on code that store `Exception.InnerException` to db:

```
try
{        
    // what should I throw here?
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    errorService.Save(ex.InnerException);
}
```

What exception (type of exception) should I throw to check my code?

Comment: Pass another `Exception` instance in `ArgumentException` ctor, like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_ArgumentException__ctor_System_String_System_Exception_)

Comment: Does it matter what the type is as long as it has an inner exception? You can easily create one just with `throw new Exception("Outer Exception", new Exception("Inner Exception"));` if that is all you need. If you need something more you'll have to give us more details...

Comment: What if there is no inner exception? You should probably check this and store `ex` if `ex.InnerException` is `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> throw new ArgumentException(); // what should I throw here?
> ```

This example isn't very clear, an ArgumentException will rarely have an innerexception. But when you really want to:

```
 new ArgumentException("parameter-name", previouseException);
```

or maybe

```
new Exception("I'm just a wrapper", new ArgumentException("parameter-name"));
```

During the handling part, what if there is no InnerException, or the InnerException again has an InnerException?

What you probably want:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    while(ex.InnerException != null)  ex = ex.InnerException;
    errorService.Save(ex);
    // throw; here unless you're very sure about handling everything 
}
```